# How to transform from exponential to trigonometric

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, transformation

I'm having trouble transforming an expression with exponentials to one with sines or cosines only.

$$u = - b a e^{-kz} e^{i(kz-wt)}$$

I know $e^{i(kz-wt)}$ is $\cos(kx-wt)$, but I can't figure out how to go from $e^{-kz}$ to a trig expression.

Could any enlightened soul please help me out?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Check out e.g. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a guide to format math here so it becomes more readable. As a hint for your question: $i^2=-1$.

Comment: I've never really thought about this before, but I guess $e^{-x} = e^{iix} = cos(ix) + i sin(ix)$

Comment: @CJD But they're not trig functions because $\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$ and $\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$ which gets you $$e^{iix}=\cosh(x)-\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}-\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} = e^{-x}$$ so no trig functions here. **BUT** if hyperbolic trig functions are allowed than that's the answer to the OP's question

Comment: @DavideMorgante Thanks for your comment and it included things I don't know about, but I can't say I agree that cos(ix) is not a trig function.  I guess we are just looking at it differently.

Comment: @CJD why should $\cos(ix)$ be a trig function? There's something I'm missing??

Comment: @DavideMorgante haha okay, do you consider cos(2*x) to be a trig function?  (I do.)  I guess we just have different definitions.

Comment: @CJC I have to think about this ahah! After all I'm just a puny physics undergraduate

Answer (score 0):

In general, $e^{\pm ix} = cos(x) \pm isin(x)$. I think you forgot to mention what $z$ is, but I assume (reading that "you know that..." ) that $z = x + iy$ an arbitrary complex number, then:
\begin{equation}
e^{-kz} = e^{-k(x+iy)} = e^{-kx}e^{-iky} = e^{-kx}(cos(ky)-isin(ky))
\end{equation}